# JavaScript console.log showing Object as Array?

Tags: javascript, logging, typeof

I am using Firebase Auth to create users and logging the error so that I can display it to the user. This logging is currently in test and goes as follows:

```
console.log(error);
console.log(typeof(error))
```

In my console I get the following:

```
[Error: [auth/invalid-email] The email address is badly formatted.]
object
```

Usually when I get an object it is returned in some kind of {} format so I am confused why it is now in seemingly-array-like format? Could someone shed on light on how this works?

Comment: The message you see in the console is just a string with some brackets in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, arrays are actually objects with some additional functionality. So `typeof([])` will return `object`.

It looks like the api is returning an array of [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) objects. If you wanted to display those errors to the user, you could loop through the returned array and print/concatenate each Error's `message` property.